# Where can I find topics for every site of this network?

Tags: support

*where can I found topics for every site of this network and differences between [superuser](http://superuser.com) and [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).*

This is perfect network where you can find answer for almost question you need. and it's free of charge. These reasons are big plus to use it.

but any way, why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018078/testing-html-email-rendering) is on StackOverflow and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/349834/installing-multiple-versions-of-ms-outlook/) is on SuperUser? 2 duplicates.

And there's much more same examples to show.

Comment: what is wrong with this question. why this question is downvote +1 from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like every online community going back to the days before WWW, in order to get the most out of a community like ServerFault, you have to put in some time and effort to figure out how it works.  If you don't put in any time, you might still get some benefit from the community, but on the other hand you might find that it doesn't work for you at all.

> Some threads such as superuser and serverfault are very nearby and difference is so small, so you always think where you should post. And there no place to check this. So I have down votes only because I put my question under different thread.

If you look at the FAQs for SF and SU, they make it pretty clear what's appropriate for each site.  They also make it clear what types of question are suited to these sites and what types are not.  Questions that require a lengthy, guidebook-style answer are one of the type that are not appropriate.

Comment: but any way, why [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018078/testing-html-email-rendering) is on StackOverflow and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/349834/installing-multiple-versions-of-ms-outlook/) is on SuperUser? 2 duplicates.

Comment: @EirNym They're not duplicates. The first is concerned with testing HTML on different rendering engines. The second is concerned with conflicting installations of MS Office. While the ultimate objective might be the same, the task is not.

Comment: Yes, as subject says. but content is referred to same task. (see 1st sentence of second topic)

Comment: The fact that the SU question mentions email templates doesn't make it a question about email templates, it's a question about installing multiple versions of Office.  Maybe there's an issue with how English is used vs. Russian, because it's very clear where those two questions should be.

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference between SU and SF. The FAQs are quite clear but as English is obviously not your native language you may not be understanding all that is on there. As this does appear, to me at least, to be mainly a language issue there isn't much we can do to make it any clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking because of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/324118/how-to-install-freebsd-when-i-have-only-windows-with-no-cd-drive). There is no definitive list of what is on or off topic on SF or SU (installing OS on a single computer). If you read our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) you will get a general feeling for what is on topic. That particular question, as asked, is a better fit for SU. If you hadn't deleted it, it would have been automagically migrated there by now.

Comment: 1) Only because of this I've received 2 down votes. 2) I've read FAQ's and haven't found many differences between thread topics

Comment: But I've stopped to post here couple months ago. and only because of very little difference.

Comment: About this particular post: Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals. Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. This is question for system administrators, so - Server Fault.

Comment: You are cutting your nose off to spite your face. 
1. Don't worry about the rep. 
2. By deleting your question you'll deny yourself an answer wherever it comes from. 
3. Your question does not appear to come from a system administrator/desktop support professional, it feels like you are a developer or a home user.

Comment: 3. it IS administrator question. and it is only because incompatibility of WinXPx32 and Win7x64. 2. Have you read it? I've asked this question in modified form in 'developer' thread (developer thread is stack overflow, you know it). 1. You'll never open down voted question even it is correct and you possibly know answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a list of every site, see: http://stackexchange.com/sites

You will probably want to check out their FAQs before deciding which ones to post on.

Comment: ServerFault and SuperUser are too close if you ask non-trivial question such as installation completely incompatible system (POSIX from Windows)

Comment: Read their FAQs, they're not really as close as you think.